# How to pivot this dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to re figure a DataFrame with the following components:

```
  Name   Date      X  Y
1 James  01/01/10  A  10
2 James  01/01/10  B  20
3 Sarah  02/01/10  A  30
4 Sarah  02/01/10  B  40
5 Sarah  03/01/10  A  50
```

Column X needs to be transposed into new columns with Name and Date grouped together. I have tried using pd.pivot and pd.pivot_table to get the resulting table below but have had no luck ie. `pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name','Date'], columns = 'X').reset_index()`

```
  Name   Date      A  B  
1 James  01/01/10  10 20
3 Sarah  02/01/10  30 40
5 Sarah  03/01/10  50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also specify `values = 'Y'`.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
  Name   Date      X  Y
1 James  01/01/10  A  hi
2 James  01/01/10  B  there
3 Sarah  02/01/10  A  textual
4 Sarah  02/01/10  B  data
5 Sarah  03/01/10  A  column"""), sep="\s+")

print(pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name','Date'], columns = 'X', values='Y', aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x)).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
X   Name      Date        A      B
0  James  01/01/10       hi  there
1  Sarah  02/01/10  textual   data
2  Sarah  03/01/10   column    NaN
```

Comment: This looks great. I'm trying it on one DataFrame though where column Y is non numeric and get the error No numeric types to aggregate. Can this be done the same way? There shouldn't be any duplicate values when grouped by name and date.

Comment: @WillacyMe, yes, you can specify your own agg func. (e.g. `aggfunc=lambda x: ‘ ‘.join(str(v) for v in x)`

Comment: @WillacyMe I've edited the answer to use a textual `Y` column

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I just need to drop the level of those new columns now as I have a second column title called <lambda>